# sql permissions problem

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a server 2012 r2 running SQL server, on the server I have a application that attaches to a data base on this server. Whats happening : I can access the database from the server and the application runs fine. When I try to access from either a windows 10 or windows 7 client it fails. All client are apart of the domain. and seem to be working fine. The application is based on foxpro and passing information to SQL over the standard port (1433). I think the problem is some sort of a permission problem. By the way everything is on a local area network in house. I have tried every thing that I know.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to **StackExchange!.**

If I understood the question correctly, `Microsoft SQL Server` (**Database Engine**) is running on `Windows Server 2012 R2` (**Operating System**) machine. Also, application running on the same machine.

You are able to access the **SQL database engine** from `local machine (Windows Server 2012 R2 machine)` but you are unable to access the database from `remote machines such as Windows 10 and Windows 7`.

Those machines are located in house and on the same network.

Lets try the following things and see, if it works for you:

1. Install `SSMS` (if you are not yet installed) client and try to access the database.
2. If you are already installed SSMS and it is not accessible, make sure you are entering the `correct username and password`.

Note that `COMPUTER1\Steven` is not same as `COMPUTER2\Steven`, if you are accessing the SQL database on local machine using **local account** (`COMPUTER1\steven`), the same username will not work, when you try from `COMPUTER2` or `Windows 7/10`. This authentication type is called **Windows Authentication**.

If this is the same issue you are facing, try using **SQL Server Authentication** mode. Create a new user on SQL Server with required permission on application database and connect to database using the newly created username and password from Windows 7/10.

For testing you can use `sa` account, which you have created, during **SQL Server database engine** installation.

Refer this page for better understanding of [SQL server Authentication Modes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/choose-an-authentication-mode?view=sql-server-2017) and make sure you enabled the **Mixed Mode Authentication** which will allow connection using both `Windows Authentication` and `SQL Server Authentication`.

3. If you tried the above options and still it is not working, check for network level issues, try the following things:

On `Windows 7/10`, open the `Command Prompt (CTRL+R -> CMD)` type the following codes and check the result:

```
ping <IP address or Hostname of the Windows Server 2012 R2>
ping 192.168.0.1
```

If you verified the `Windows Server 2012 R2` is reachable from `Windows 7/10`. Then there is no connectivity problem. Otherwise, fix the connectivity issue and try access from Windows 7/10 (remote) machines. Refer this [page](https://serverfault.com/questions/18506/what-to-check-if-pinging-doesnt-work), if ping not working.

4. If the `Windows Server 2012 R2 IP or Hostname is pinging (reachable)` but still SQL database is not accessible from remote machine, check whether `Port 1433 is opened and listening on Windows Server 2012`. Type the following command on `Command Prompt` on `remote machine` and check the result:

> telnet 192.168.0.1 1433

This will help you verify, whether the port opened or not. If it failed, check this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/configure-the-windows-firewall-to-allow-sql-server-access?view=sql-server-2017).

5. If you are successful with ping and telnet result, but still not accessible check whether `TCP/IP protocol enabled` on [SQL server configuration manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/configuration-manager/sql-server-network-configuration?view=sql-server-2017).
6. If none of the above methods working, refer this page for [troubleshooting SQL Server Database connectivity issues.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/troubleshoot-connecting-to-the-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017)

After trying all of the above methods and still if it is not working, just edit the question with specific error message. (**providing error message or more details about the issue you are facing will help you get the answer quickly and other people will most likely to answer to your question**).

Once you are done with all of the above workarounds, I hope you will get **better understanding about how SQL Server Database Engine access and networking works**. I hope this answer helps. Thanks!